# Mavericks: notifications no longer displaying

Tags: macos, spotlight, notifications, bug, ui

I recently upgraded to Mavericks (download from app store).

Before this upgrade, I could click on the the notifications UI element at the very top-right of the display; this would cause the whole screen to shift to the left and display a list of notifications:

[image]

Now, after the upgrade, this UI element simply turns blue during the mousedown, and nothing else happens.

Are there any known fixes or workarounds to this?

---

I should add I am experiencing a similar but not identical issue with the spotlight UI element:

[image]

When I click on this one, I just get a "bonk" sound and no spotlight search bar.  ***However*** I can use spotlight without problems from finder windows, etc.

---

I don't know, but I'm guessing these two issues may be related simply because of their proximity on the screen.

Other taskbar UI elements appear to be working normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, check your settings in System Preferences > Notifications. You may have Do Not Disturb enabled.
>
> For com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist. It's located in your user library, not root level where you may be looking.
>
> Open the Finder. From the Finder menu bar click Go > Go to Folder
>
> Type or copy paste the following:
>
> ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
>
> Click Go then move the com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist file to the Trash.
>
> Restart your Mac.
>
> I can't locate the com.apple.soagent.plist in either user or root.
>
> If deleting the com.apple.notificationui.plist file did not help, reinstall OS X >  OS X Mavericks: Reinstall OS X
>
> That will reinstall any missing system files required for the Notification center.

From https://discussions.apple.com/message/25351691#25351691